# Snowpark Python Equivalent of the Pipe function in Pandas

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Pandas, we are able to use Pipe to do method chaining to enhance code readability:

```
df = (pd.read_csv('data.csv')/
     .pipe(convert_names_to_upper)/
     .pipe(deidentify)
)
```

The two custom functions can be any arbitrary function that transforms the Dataframe.
The question is, is there an equivalent method in Snowpark Python to create custom functions in the python code file and chain them using a syntax similar to Pipe in Pandas? If not, is there an elegant workaround?

I was not able to attempt any solutions after viewing the Snowpark API docs.

Comment: I think the answer is "no".

Answer (score 0):

No such thing exists in SnowPark to my knowlegde. You could however look into alternative packages to construct a pipeline like:

- [SKLearn Pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html)
- [Hamilton](https://github.com/DAGWorks-Inc/hamilton/)

This way you can wrap your functions that call Snowpark into something which nicely structures and runs the pipeline.